# Issue in Upgrading to Angular 2.0 from Angular RC 4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I am upgrading my project from Angular RC 4 to newly released Angular 2.0
However, I am getting following errors while running `npm install`:

Error:

> Module '/../...' has no exported member 'REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES'

My package.json file has an entry as:

> "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",

And my Component file imports are as follows:

> import {FormGroup, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All deprecated forms APIs and `REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES` API are removed since [angular rc6](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc6-2016-08-31) so you have to import `FormsModule` in your `AppModule`. Check [Forms User Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)